# Is "with_connection" necessary with "exec_query"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm occasionally getting `PG::TRDeadlockDetected` on a Rails with PostgreSQL app (served via Passenger/Nginx) and traced it down to places in the code which use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exececute`.

In order to fix this, I'm replacing `.execute` with `.exec_query` or `.exec_update` as per what the docs recommend. However, it's not really made clear whether `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query` gets the connection from the connection pool or not.

- When using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query` in a Rails controller, does it have to be wrapped with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection`? *(my guess: yes)*
- When using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query` outside of the context of a request (say a Rake tasks executed as cronjob), does it have to be wrapped with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection`? *(my guess: yes)*

And if wrapping is necessary, are there shorter alternatives compared to:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |connection|
  connection.exec_update "REINDEX INDEX my_complex_index"
end
```

*(my guess: no)*

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: Interesting, got any source for that? I'm experiencing the same issue with the same stack. Was not too sure about what causes it and just realized it started occuring after I added model methods that call raw sql with `.execute`.

Comment: Seems threading related to me

Comment: @mkrl The `execute` vs `exec_query` is in fact unrelated to the deadlock but should assure proper cleanup.

Comment: @mkrl As for the connection pool, I've plowed through the AR source, but I'm not 100% sure I got things right (and therefore ask here). My guess is, the deadlock occurs when different threads pick up the same connection and create circular locks. The pooling of connections should prevent this.

Comment: @svoop yes, I was thinking of that. Not sure about your case, but I'm using the open-source version. As far as I know, only passenger enterprise is able to spawn additional threads.